# using simple void pointer for arrays of C strings

Tags: c, pointers

so I have this code, goal is to have a `void *data` pointer, which is sometimes used to store a simple `int`, sometimes a single `char` array and sometimes I need to store an array of char arrays.
I'm making sure that I always know what type of data I have stored in the void pointer.

The code executes well in an online parser and this is the output of it:

> ```
> sizeof 2 x char*: 8
>
> str0: string1 addr: 2995278544
>
> str1: bla2 addr: 2995278576
>
> checking strings:
>
> str0: string1 addr: 2995278544
>
> str1: bla2 addr: 2995278576
> ```

The plan was to malloc space for n char* pointers and save that pointer do void *data. Then change the type to "char **ptr" (pointer to a pointer), so I can save the addresses which strdup returns to that array and access them later.
checkItems(uint8_t) does exactly that, it re-accesses the "void *data" pointer by changing it to "char **ptr" again to be able to access the memory addresses where the actual C strings are saved.

is this all correct? would one do this differently? should I use some kind of cast to the void *data pointer instead simply saying "char **ptr = data;"?

Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

void copyItems(uint8_t num, ...);
void checkItems(uint8_t num);

void *data;

int main()
{
    copyItems(2, "string1", "bla2");
    checkItems(2);
}

void copyItems(uint8_t num, ...)
{
    printf("sizeof %u x char*: %u\r\n", num, sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*)*num);
    data = malloc(sizeof(char*)*num);
    
    char **ptr = data;
    
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);
    
    for (uint8_t n = 0; n < num; n++)
    {
        ptr[n] = strdup(va_arg(ap, char*));
        printf("str%u: %s addr: %u\r\n", n, ptr[n], ptr[n]);
    }
    
    va_end(ap);
}

void checkItems(uint8_t num)
{
    char **ptr = data;
    
    printf("checking strings:\r\n");
    
    for (uint8_t n = 0; n < num; n++)
    {
        printf("str%u: %s addr: %u\r\n", n, ptr[n], ptr[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm making sure that I always know what type of data I have stored in the void pointer."* Where? I would have expected that information to be contained in a `struct` along with the pointer, *and* the number of items stored.

Comment: yes, in fact the void pointer is contained within a struct where all the info is stored (including the number of items, of course). as I'm not having any issues with that, I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: You shouldn't (need to) cast a void pointer, please see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: i figured that I can also say ((char**)data)[n] instead of creating char **ptr. question stays, whether this is allowed, correct and good practice, or just pure BS...

Comment: If you are *dereferencing* the `void*` pointer, then you must cast it. For assigning to another pointer type, no.

Comment: @WeatherVane if I just try to access the array element via data[n], where data is the void pointer, I get a "dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer" error.

Comment: Which supports what I wrote.

Comment: If I were to store 1 out of 3 types in a variable, I would use a `union`.

Comment: yes, we overlapped here. so is this correct how I did it? it seems to me but I'd like to be more confident. do you or does anyone have a thread or an article handy where a similar thing has been discussed/explained?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would store size and type information in the structure

```
typedef enum
{
    INT, 
    CHAR,
    CHARPTR,
}DATA_TYPE;

typedef struct 
{
    DATA_TYPE dtype;
    size_t size;
    void *data;
}DATA;

DATA *copyItems(size_t num, DATA_TYPE type, ...);
void PrintItems(const DATA *data);

size_t datasize(const DATA *data)
{
    size_t result;
    switch(data -> dtype)
    {
        case INT:
            result = sizeof(int);
            break;
        case CHAR:
            result = 1;
            break;
        case CHARPTR:
            result = sizeof(char *);
            break;
        default: 
            result = 0;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}




int main()
{
    DATA *data =  copyItems(2, CHARPTR, "string1", "bla2");
    PrintItems(data);
}

DATA *copyItems(size_t num, DATA_TYPE type, ...)
{
    DATA *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
        
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, type);
    
    if(data)
    {
        data -> size = 0;
        data -> data = malloc(datasize(data) * num);
        data -> dtype = type;
        if(data -> data)
        {
            for (size_t n = 0; n < num; n++, data -> size++)
            {
                switch(data -> dtype)
                {
                    case INT:
                        ((int *)data -> data)[n] = va_arg(ap, int);
                        break;
                    case CHARPTR:
                        ((char **)data -> data)[n] = strdup(va_arg(ap, char *));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        { /* error handler */}
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return data;
}

void PrintItems(const DATA *data)
{
    if(data && data -> size && data -> data)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < data -> size; i++)
        {
            switch(data -> dtype)
            {
                case INT:
                    printf("[%zu] = %d\n", i, ((int *)data -> data)[i]);
                    break;
                case CHARPTR:
                    printf("[%zu] = %s\n", i, ((char **)data -> data)[i]);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PjWhrGvvP

Comment: thank you, I actually already have a struct where the void pointer is stored, and I very likely would have saved the necessary infos like you did, alongside in the struct. in any case this gives me approval that this method is ok and allowed/working. however I'm curious what you are thinking about the Union approach of @arfneto. which approach is more betterer or more common/best practice? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of *variant record*, present in C and many languages like Pascal, and maybe you could stick to the usual.

In `C` we can use anonymous unions to this effect.

I will show you a short example.

> Note that I will not implement here the logic to copy the strings to a
> new vector, and it is important for safety. Please comment if you
> think you need an example.

#### The data structure example

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char id;  // 1,2,3
    union
    {
        unsigned char the_char;
        unsigned char size;  // up to 255 strings
    };
    union
    {
        int          the_int;
        const char** argv;
    };

} Data;
```

The reason for the 1st union is described below, but it also helps to keep the size of `Data` even and it is useful sometimes, for alignment purposes.

The 2nd union is optional and exists for the *non-char* cases, so the minimum size of `Data` is 2 bytes.

Here we use `id` as `1` for `char`, `2` for `int` and `3` for a vector of strings.

- When holding a single `char` it follows the `id` so we use just 2 bytes
- When holding an `int` it follows these 2 bytes
- When using strings the code has 2 options:

  - for up to 255 strings the count is put at the `size` component, giving an alternate meaning for the 2nd byte of `Data`.
  - When `size` is `0` the vector is assumed to be null-terminated and this is useful when there can be a huge number of strings that would overflow size

#### output

```
char: '?'

int: Value is 42

array of strings: [4 in total]

        #1      an
        #2      array
        #3      of
        #4      strings


array of strings [null-terminated]:

        #1      an
        #2      array
        #3      of
        #4      strings
        #5      ends here

5 strings were found...
```

#### the code

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char id;  // 1,2,3
    union
    {
        unsigned char the_char;
        unsigned char size;  // up to 255 strings
    };
    union
    {
        int          the_int;
        const char** argv;
    };

} Data;

int check_one(Data*);
int valid_id(Data*);

int main(void)
{
    const char* words[] = {"an",      "array",     "of",
                           "strings", "ends here", NULL};

    Data data[4];

    data[0].id       = 1;
    data[0].the_char = '?';

    data[1].id      = 2;
    data[1].the_int = 42;

    data[2].id   = 3;
    data[2].size = 4;
    data[2].argv = words;

    data[3].id   = 3;
    data[3].size = 0;  // signals the array as null-terminated
    data[3].argv = words;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) check_one(&data[i]);

    return 0;
}

int check_one(Data* d)
{
    const char* what[] = {NULL, "char", "int", "array of strings"};
    if (d == NULL) return -1;
    if (not valid_id(d)) return -2;
    switch (d->id)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("\n%s: '%c'\n", what[d->id], d->the_char);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n%s: Value is %d\n", what[d->id], d->the_int);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (d->size != 0)
            {  // known size
                printf("\n%s: [%d in total]\n\n", what[d->id], d->size);
                for (int i = 0; i < d->size; i += 1)
                    printf("\t#%d\t%s\n", 1 + i, d->argv[i]);
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            };
            // ok: the array is NULL-terminated
            printf("\n%s [null-terminated]:\n\n", what[d->id]);
            int sz = 0;
            for (; d->argv[sz] != NULL; sz += 1)
                printf("\t#%d\t%s\n", 1 + sz, d->argv[sz]);
            printf("\n%d strings were found...\n\n", sz);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
int valid_id(Data* d) { return ((d->id > 0) && (d->id < 4)); };
```

Comment: interesting approach, thanks for explaining! (why) do you think, this is a better approach than the one from @0___________ ?

Comment: I did not said it is better or worse. I did not even had read the other until now. What I can say is that what I wrote is flexible: (a) it is easy to can change the implementation and add new message types. (b) It is easy to serialize, in order to transmit as a buffer or write to a file. (c) The 2 functions makes changing easier (d) in a real implementation you will need to prepare and copy the data (e) the data includes format so you do need to "make sure" anything

Comment: and is the common way to write this, like in Pascal _variant records_